# How can I optimize this Python code to run faster?

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I'm solving a problem which has some time and memory constraints, and unfortunately this is failing the time constraints.

I'm fairly new to Python, so any feedback on faster/better methods is appreciated.

This is the problem the program is trying to solve:

Define the similarity of two strings A & B as the length of the longest common prefix that they share. i.e the similarity of AAAB and AABCAAAB is 2.

The program should output the sum of similarities of the input string with all of its suffixes. i.e for AAAB, it should output

similarity(AAAB,AAAB) + similarity(AAAB,AAB) + similarity(AAAB,AB) +similarity(AAAB,B) = 4 + 2 + 1 + 0 = 7

The first line of input is the number of strings to be entered, and each subsequent line contains a string to be processed.

```
from array import array

n = int(sys.stdin.readline()) 
A = [0] * n #List of answers

for i in range(1,n+1):
  string = sys.stdin.readline().strip()    
  A[i-1] = len(string)
  for j in range(1, len(string)):
    substr = string[j:len(string)]
    sum = 0
    for k in range(0, len(substr)):
        if substr[k] != string[k]:
            break
        else:
            sum += 1
    A[i-1] += sum

for i,d in enumerate(A):
  print d
```

Comment: If you are using python 2.x, you can start by changing all those `range` to `xrange`.  Is there any good reason you need to read from input line-by-line rather than in one big chunk?

Comment: By the way, the real issue is getting rid of that triple nested loop.  I'm sure there is some clever logic you can reimplement it with!

Comment: You should look for faster algorithm.

Comment: it's rather a very small issue, but still. 
there are 3 "len(string)" in the loop. I think that calculating it once with "len_string=len(string)" and using len_string later on, saves 2 calculations of len() function. Or maybe Python does it automatically, does anybody know it?

Comment: I doubt Python does it automatically, since its possible that `len(string)` changes between two calls (although it doesn't in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of performance prefer xrange as its faster for iterating in python2.X  But the best advice I can give is to use [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) to measure the changes and improvements whilst tweaking your algorithm.

Having googled theres another implementation here: [Longest Common substring](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#Python) solution but the [python-Levenshtein](https://github.com/miohtama/python-Levenshtein) library is probably your best bet as it has C extension for speed...

Comment: Now that I think about it, the core algorithm itself can be improved upon by a lot, so I'm going to work on that. The minor fixes (`xrange`, reading input line-by-line) were insufficient.

This isn't exactly the Longest Common Substring problem, but it's close and I'm going to apply a similar idea, so I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to reduce the amount of indexing you're doing:

```
import sys

n = int(sys.stdin.readline())

for i in range(n):
    string = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    sum = 0
    for offset in range(len(string)):
        suffix = string[offset:]
        for c1, c2 in zip(string, suffix):
            if c1 != c2:
                break
            sum += 1
    print sum
```

This is still O(N^2), though.  For O(N), use a suffix tree or array, such as http://code.google.com/p/pysuffix/

Answer (score 1):

You can try an alternate implementation

```
sum(len(os.path.commonprefix([instr,instr[i:]])) for i in xrange(0,len(instr)))
```

where instr = Your said String